# Xcode: overwrite compilation parameters of a .c/.cpp file

Tags: xcode4

I'm very familiar with MS's Visual Studio environment, and recently I had to do some stuff for iPhone. I have a c++ project and I have performance critical components included as part of the project. This performance critical file absolutely must be compiled using optimized settings even for debug builds. That is, I have to overwrite settings for a file and pass -O2 -DNDEBUG when compiling one of the files of the project without affecting default compilation settings of the rest of the project.

Can this be done, I spent like an hour browsing through menus of XCode and wasn't able to find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to your project window and select the file, you can get info on it with command-i or right clicking.  Then go to the build tab, where you can enter additional compilation flags for this particular file.

I am on xcode 3.x but I don't imagine that they would remove this.

I note that this is just for additional compiler flags.  If you need to remove some of your default flags the only option I can think of is a bit of a pain: make a new target that is set up with build options just for this file and include that target in your main target.

Comment: I use XCode4 and it seems that command-I is configured to start Profiler and does not open file specific configuration options.